# How to safely retry a failed jQuery ajax POST request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, post, idempotent

In RESTful architecture, POST requests are neither *Safe* nor *Idempotent*.

Now jQuery's ajax calls allow for retrying of requests that fail, by setting the ajax call to use the `error` function to catch the failure, and to optionally retry the call (along with associated settings such as `timeout`, `tryCount`, `retryAfter` and `retryLimit`).

Retrying GET calls is not a problem (since they're both *safe* and *idempotent*), but how should one go about retrying a POST call?

For example, let's say we're using ajax POST to insert a new record:

1. An ajax POST call is initiated on the client.
2. The call is received by the server, which updates the database.
3. The server responds, but this response fails to deliver to the client.
4. So the client assumes there was a failure, and retries the call.
5. The call is received again by the server, which makes another change.
6. And so on...

What would be the best way to cater for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

The only way your code can rest easy (pardon the pun), is to get confirmation that the data has been received and accepted.

So the answer actually depends on the nature of the POST.  If the POST is really an update, such as set name to "John", then you could safely retry a few times until you get confirmation.

However, the case you are talking about is when a POST is really a POST in the REST sense, meaning typically that it will add a new row.  In that case, the proper way to do depends on a deeper handshake between the client and server.

In the end, data integrity is the job of the code handling the database, so the server code.  Therefore, if rows should not be duplicated, then the scenario will proceed as follows:

- Client makes a GET for a "submission token", including a client-generated ID.
- Server generates a submission token based on clientID, and stores it in a table
- Server sends the token to the Client
- Client submits POST including the token.
- Server receives token, verifies it, inserts the post, and responds with success

  1. So, if a GET token request doesn't make it to the server, the client can request again, always using the same clientID.
  2. If the client eventually gets back a token, he can assume the server has a record of his request and is expecting a followup POST.
  3. If the client ends up getting more than one token responses after a few failures, they will all be the same token.
  4. So then the client will POST, and keep posting (with the token), until he receives success
  5. If the server ever gets one of the posts, it will insert the data and invalidate the token and respond success.
  6. If the server ever gets a request and has already used the token, it responds with "duplicate request"
  7. The client can only ever receive 1 "success", and if the client happens to not receive it, then on future attempts it will get the "duplicate request" and also know that it was inserted.

Now, if the server doesn't care about duplicates and you have no control over it, and it's just the client, then the best solution is just to wait a long time before trying again, and always alternate get and post.   You can theoretically never know though, because maybe they have a queue that collects requests while the server is offline, and next week they'll process them.